# Letter appeared in data when arff loaded into Python

Tags: python, pandas, weka, arff

I have loaded an arff file to python using this code:

```
import pandas as pd, scipy as sp
from scipy.io import arff
datos,meta = arff.loadarff(open('selectividad.arff', 'r'))
d = pd.DataFrame(datos)
```

When I use head function to see the data frame, this is how it looks:
[image]

However, those 'b' are not present in the arff file as we can see below:
https://gyazo.com/3123aa4c7007cb4d6f99241b1fc41bcb
What is the problem here? Thank you very much

Comment: Those `b` are python's way of displaying a `bytes` array and are not part of the data.

Comment: Those `b` indicate you're treating a byte string, litterally a sequence of octets, whcih are ASCII cahracters. You can decode them using `.decode("utf-8")` for instance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For one column, apply the following code:

```
data['name_column'] = data['name_column'].str.decode('utf-8')
```

For a dataframe, apply:

```py
str_df = df.select_dtypes([object])
str_df = str_df.stack().str.decode('utf-8').unstack()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add an explanation to the answer. How does it solve the problem? Regards.