# Values begin with 'b' when reading an arff file to pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, arff

I'm reading in [this arff file](https://www.openml.org/search?type=data&status=active&id=40536) to a pandas dataframe in Colab. I've used the following code, which seems to be fairly standard, from what a quick scan of top search results tells me.

```
from scipy.io.arff import loadarff 

raw_data = loadarff('/speeddating.arff')
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data[0])
```

When I inspect the dataframe, many of the values appear in this format: `b'some_text'`.

When I call `type(df.iloc[0,0])` it returns `bytes`.

What is happening, and how do I get it to not be that way?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else stumbles upon this question, I found it answered here: [Letter appeared in data when arff loaded into Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49806439/letter-appeared-in-data-when-arff-loaded-into-python)